# Не обновляется привязка в WPF C# при привязке к Dictionary

Tags: wpf, словари, binding

В моей программе View формируется динамически в зависимости от количества выбранных параметров.
вот таким образом:

```
foreach(PARAMS p in parameters)
{
  var item = new TextBlock();
  Binding binding  = new Binding();
  binding.Source = vm.valueController.values[p];
  binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
  binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
  
  item.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
  ParametersValue.Children.Add(item);

}
```

При создании в текст-блоках устанавливаются значения согласно значениям в словаре values <PARAMS, Double>. Однако при обновлении значений в values они не обновляются.
При установке binding.Path=new PropertyPath("."); ничего не меняется, при установке другого проперти, не устанавливаются даже изначальные значения

INotifyPropertyChanged  реализует ValueController
вызывая PropertyChanged  при вызове функции setValues[p] = ...

Comment: Не страдайте ерундой, есть XAML и это неотъемлемая часть WPF, почему вы им пренебрегаете? Также где у вас INPC?

Comment: потому что xaml статичен, в нем находится элемент parametersValue. мне надо чтобы при открытии окна отображались только параметры из листа parameters.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, XAML имеет уйму всего, что позволяет сделать динамику, вот прям уйму. Допустим `foreach(PARAMS p in parameters)` = `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Parameters}">...`, а `var item = new TextBlock();` - это стиль этого `ItemsControl`. Вот у вас и будет на экране тож самое. Так что совет тот же, не страдайте ерундой, а научитесь использовать WPF правильно!

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged реализует ValueController вызывая PropertyChanged при вызове функции setValues[p] = ...` - это надо показывать, не описывать текстом. Сейчас предположу, что у вас он обновляет не то свойство, что надо.